# CM4 eMMC - safe shutdown / power supply schemes

Tags: power, filesystem, shutdown, compute-module

I'm working on a design that uses a CM4 with eMMC and may (optionally) use an external SD card or USB stick for "user" file storage.

The unit could (potentially) be hard powered-down by the user or by mains interruption without notice. However, it won't be doing much and shouldn't be reading or writing to the filesystem beyond whatever the OS does in the background.

I'm trying to work out a simple, robust approach to the power supply for the CM4 to avoid corruption but also without having to add too much complexity or lengthy shutdown delays.

I've seen scripts that monitor GPIO pins and shut the unit down when a pin changes state, this looks good as a starter but of course if the 5v starts dropping you've only got so much time to shut down safely.

I guess this spawns a few direct questions;

1. How quickly can/does the CM4 shutdown running standard Raspbian or other mainstream OS images?
2. Is one of the other mainstream supported OS'es (EG Ubuntu) significantly faster to shutdown / can be made so without major changes?
3. Are there steps that can be taken to "blackout-proof" the OS, so that (for example) the filesystem is not left in a state that would cause problems.

I know it's *possible* to configure the filesystem as read-only at boot but that then precludes software updates - ideally it would be good to have it run from RAM or similar in such a way that changes are only written to the FS occasionally and they're always completely flushed so the FS is not left in a "bad" state.

I am pretty sure this is both possible and fairly commonly done in embedded linux but I'm rusty on the details and what to search for.

Comment: Not so sure about hardware design, but I know that Raspberry OS / debian will shut down significantly quicker the fewer systemd services you have running. I would consider cutting down on those first. Perhaps even timing them to know which one you should remove. On top of that you can have a read-only filesystem during normal operations and switch to write mode when updates are required.

Comment: You can also consider to use a battery as a PSU - but that makes shipping a product waay more tedious and probably not worth it.